# EF Core query where sum of relationship is less than property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm having to classes, one product class and one which tracks the orders. Both are stored in a database and I'm using ef core as the orm.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AvailableQuantity { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to get all Products where the sum of the `Order.Quantity` is less than the `Product.AvailableQuantity` and the `Order.Confirmed` property is true.

I already tried

```
_context.Products.Where(product => product.Orders.Where(order => order.Confirmed).Sum(order => order.Quantity) < product.AvailableQuantity)
```

but that obviously didn't work. I'm guessing I need something with `GroupBy`, but I can't get my head around how to get this query to work.
Also I don't want to use `AsEnumerable` and execute the query in memory, because my database is huge.

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException`
Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringMethod()

Comment: can you try using `select` in place of where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> Get all Products where the sum of the Order.Quantity is less than the Product.AvailableQuantity and the Order.Confirmed property is true.

I think you meant to say the following:

**Requirement**: Get all Products, with their confirmed orders, where the sum of the Quantity of these confirmed orders is less than the AvailableQuantity of the Product.

If might be that you also want the non-confirmed orders in your end result. This won't change a lot.

```
var result = dbContext.Products.Where(product =>

    // keep only the Products where the sum of the confirmed orders is less than ...
    product.Orders.Where(order => order.Confirmed)
                  .Select(order => order.Quantity)
                  .Sum() < product.AvailableQuantity);
```

This will give you the products with **all** their Orders: the confirmed ones and the non-confirmed ones.

If you only want the confirmed ones, consider using a Select first:

```
var productsThatCanBeDelivered = dbContext.Products.Select(product => new
{
    // Select only the product properties that you plan to use:
    Id = product.Id,
    AvailableQuantity = product.AvailableQuantity,

    ConfirmedOrders = product.Orders
        .Where(order => order.Confirmed)
        .Select(order => new
        {
            // select only the order properties that you plan to use
            Id = order.Id,
            Quantity = order.Quantity,
            ...

            // no need for this: you already know the value
            // ProductId = order.ProductId,
            // Confirmed = order.Confirmed,
        })
        .ToList(),
    })

    // keep only those Products where the quantities of the confirmed orders is less than ...
    .Where(product => product.ConfirmedOrders
                             .Select(confiredOrder => confirmedOrder.Quantity)
                             .Sum() < product.AvailableQuantity);
```

One final remark: are you sure you mean less than AvailableQuantity, not less or equal:
if there is 1 Available product, and you only need to deliver one, why not deliver it?

Comment: Thanks, that is the right way and working fine, but when there are products which habe no orders, these are not displayed. Also I just need the products, the orders are not required so your first solution is fine

Comment: Changing `.Sum() < product.AvailableQuantity` to `.Sum() <= product.AvailableQuantity` and adding `|| p.Orders.Count == 0` does the trick and I'm getting the correct set of products. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
_context.Orders.Where(c => c.Confirmed).AsQueryable().GroupBy(c => c.ProductId)
               .Where(c => c.Sum(d => d.Quantity) < c.First().Product.AvailableQuantity)
               .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c);
```

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: I tired it, but I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException` -  "The LINQ expression ... could not be translated."

Comment: I think the problem is in the c.First() statement which needs to be executed on the client

Comment: This is not solvable then with the EF Core version used. 3.x version are quite limited in waht they can do in SQL, and even 5.x versions are CURRENTLY not really better.